# BASH variable never set

Tags: xml, bash, awk

Hi im trying to set a variable from an XML stream, i can output the the event from the XML stream using this command

```
curl -s http://admin:12345@10.1.1.51/Event/notification/alertStream |
    awk -F"[<>]" '/eventDescription/{print $3}'
```

The Xml stream continually outputs the eventDescription every second. My question how do output it to a variable in a BASH script.

Doing this is not working, i think its because the Xml stream never stops outputing.

```
MY_EVENT=$(curl -s http://admin:12345@10.1.1.51/Event/notification/alertStream |
    awk -F"[<>]" '/eventDescription/{print $3}')
```

Comment: An alternative to $() is using back-ticks. Without having a reproducible `curl` command, it's next to impossible to offer any constructive advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
MY_EVENT=$(
    curl -s "$url" | \
    awk -F"[<>]" '/eventDescription/{print $3; exit}'
)
```

Note the `exit` to stop processing after the first match.

Comment: You don't need to escape a newline immediately after a pipe. The shell will assume you want to continue the command.

Comment: @kojiro: Thanks. Will leave it here so your comment keeps on making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue is that the curl command continues providing output forever, you need something that will regularly flush the buffer to the command on the other end of the pipe. POSIX awk itself does not have such a command, but BSD awk does have a `fflush` function (I'm on OS X).

Comment: I am not so sure... I guess the variable is only set for real when the subshell ends. ``id=$(echo 123; sleep 3; echo 456)`` will only return control after the subshell exits, at which moment the variable assignment will happen.